# Can't get my method to upper case my string arrays

Tags: c#, loops

The whole program is listed after, but the only problem i have with it is the `ToUppers()` method. I just want this method to iterate over each string in my array, and then make everything upper case.

```
        private static string[] ToUppers(string[] stringToUpperArrays)
        {
            string stringer;

            foreach (string value in stringToUpperArrays)
            {
                stringer = value.ToUpper(); // <== this line highlighted
                Console.WriteLine(stringer);
            }
            return stringToUpperArrays;
        }
```

The program executes after it prints it on the console, and it lists a `NullReferenceException`, and highlights the `stringer = value.ToUpper();` line

The whole program

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Utility;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Mark Bouwman
            //CNT A01
            //ICA18
            //April 2nd

            string answer;
            int numInArray;
            string[] stringArrays;
            string[] stringArraysToDisplay;
            string[] stringToUpperArrays;

            //TITLE
            Console.WriteLine("\t\tStringy");

            do
            {
                numInArray = Utility.Utility.GetInt(2, 10, "Enter the size of the array from 2 to 10: ");
                stringArrays = CreateArray(numInArray);
                stringArraysToDisplay = Display(stringArrays);
                stringToUpperArrays = ToUppers(stringArrays);






                //aksing to run program again
                Console.Write("Run program again? yes or no: ");
                answer = Console.ReadLine();                
            }
            while (answer.Equals("yes", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
        }

        private static string[] CreateArray(int numInArray)
        {
            int index;
            string[] stringArray;

            stringArray = new string[(numInArray + 1)];
            for (index = 0; index < numInArray; ++index)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter string #" + (index + 1) + " ");
                stringArray[index] = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            return stringArray;
        }

        private static string[] Display(string[] stringArraysDisplay)
        {
            foreach (string value in stringArraysDisplay)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(value);
            }
            return stringArraysDisplay;
        }

        private static string[] ToUppers(string[] stringToUpperArrays)
        {
            string stringer;

            foreach (string value in stringToUpperArrays)
            {
                stringer = value.ToUpper();
                Console.WriteLine(stringer);
            }
            return stringToUpperArrays;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `CreateArray` you define the array to size of `numInArray + 1` but you fill the array only with `numInArray` strings, i.e. the last index is empty. When you try `value.ToUpper();` on the empty index you get the exception.

In `CreateArray` change

```
stringArray = new string[(numInArray + 1)];
```

To

```
stringArray = new string[numInArray];
```

Or change

```
for (index = 0; index < numInArray; ++index)
{
    Console.Write("Enter string #" + (index + 1) + " ");
    stringArray[index] = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

To

```
for (index = 0; index < stringArray.Length; ++index)
{
    Console.Write("Enter string #" + (index + 1) + " ");
    stringArray[index] = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should erase the + 1 when you are initializing the array

```
stringArray = new string[(numInArray)];
```

in this method

```
 private static string[] CreateArray(int numInArray)
```

Comment: This does not answer the question